# android:icon is not showing on some devices

Tags: android, icons, launcher

For my android application I have defined a launcher icon like this:

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

I have put an **ic_launcher.png** file in all the *drawable* folders.

The logo of my app is displayed on all devices except for some. Someone showed me today how it's installed on a Samsung Galaxy Pocket (running 2.3.6 - gingerbread) and there it shows a default android icon instead of the one i have defined.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Did you scale the logo appropriately for each resolution or just copied the default logo?

Comment: Ok, this was a non-issue. One of the designers had put the default android icon in the lowres folder :S

Answer (score 1):

place this image in drawable folder. If it is not already created then create it